# UIImage Print Description Output in Xcode Debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging, uiimage

I have a simple question, but I can't find the answer in Apple Documentation on the Xcode Debugger. When you select a UIImage variable and push the "Print Description" (i in a circle) button, the output you get is something like this:

```
Printing description of image:
<UIImage: 0x6000002b23c0>, {600, 550}
```

I presume the hexadecimal is the memory location, but what is the tuple in brackets {600, 550}? If not, what is it? Is it the size of the image? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to display further info about your object variable by doing a "po" command in the Console lldb window.
[image: po command gives info on UIImage object]